# Date range change dynamically per rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need to do a specif date range for each row of my query result, example:

```
    select 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_purchase, '%Y-%m')as Year_month,
    count(*) as Count
    from tickets 
    where date_purchase BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'
group by Year_month
```

This query give that result :

```
Year_month | Count
2019-01    | 134
2019-02    | 154
2019-03    | 123
```

But i need to add one more column to comparing to the count of one year ago, the expected result would be like this:

```
Year_month | Count | Count_One_Year_Ago_Per_Month
2019-01    | 134   | (count(*) between 2018-01 and 2019-01)
2019-02    | 154   | (count(*) between 2018-02 and 2019-02)
2019-03    | 123   | (count(*) between 2018-03 and 2019-03)
```

How is the best way to do that ?

EDIT: My Mysql version is 5.7

Answer (score 1):

If you have data for all months, the simplest method is to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select date_format(sa.date_purchase, '%Y-%m') as Year_month,
             count(*) as Count,
             lag(count(*), 12) over (order by min(sa.date_purchase) as count_year_ago
      from tickets t
      group by Year_month
     ) t
where year_month between '2019-01' and '2019-03';
```

EDIT:

You can also use conditional aggregation:

```
select month(date_purchase),
       sum(year(date_purchase) = 2018) as cnt_2018,
       sum(year(date_purchase) = 2019) as cnt_2019
from tickets t
where date_purchase >= '2018-01-01' and
      date_purchase < '2019-04-01' and
      month(date_purchase) in (1, 2, 3)
group by month(date_purchase);
```

I think you might need a correlated subquery if you want a full years worth of counts:

```
select ym.*,
       (select count(*)
        from tickets t2
        where date_format(t2.date_purchase, '%Y-%m') < ym.year_month and
              date_format(t2.date_purchase + interval 1 year, '%Y-%m') >= ym.year_month
       ) as prev_cumulative_year
from (select date_format(sa.date_purchase, '%Y-%m') as Year_month,
             count(*) as Count
      from tickets t
      group by Year_month
     ) ym
```

Comment: One detail that i forgot to mention, my MYSQL version is 5.7.26, so i cant use LAG function :/

Comment: Thank you, but the EDIT give me the count of each month in each year, not the full rage of one year ex:(count between 2018-01 and 2019-01).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this script-

You can check the [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aca0e3a9008e3b9e92a6aaba9d572e4f) with some sample data.

```
SELECT 
A.date_purchase,
MAX(c_count) Current_month_count,
COUNT(*) last_year_count
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_purchase, '%Y-%m') AS `date_purchase`,
    COUNT(*) c_count 
    FROM tickets
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_purchase, '%Y-%m')
)A
INNER JOIN tickets B 
    ON  A.date_purchase 
    BETWEEN

        DATE_FORMAT(B.date_purchase, '%Y-%m')
        AND
        DATE_FORMAT(B.date_purchase + interval 12 month, '%Y-%m')

GROUP BY A.date_purchase
```